# CSS-HTML-Resize screen

Tags: html, css, resize

He there!

I working on a Basic website to learn to understand the coding.
What i don't understand is this.

In CSS i have a container: width 80%
Inside i have a header: height 270px
Inside the header i have a Menu. height: 65px

i didnt set a width for the header and the menu because the width from the container is 80% thats good thinking? or not?

Well, it works but. what doesn't work is this..
i want to have the menu fixed because when i scrol i want to have my menu going with me.

position: fixed; - and my menu is shorter ?WHY? when i set a width of 79% i will correct this. But if i resize my screen the menu wil go outside my container on the right side.. i don't understand why? because it is in the container.

Can someone explain?

CSS-

```css
#container {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -1%;
    padding: 0 10%;}
#header {
    height: 270px;
    background-color: gainsboro;}
#menu {
    height: 65px;
    
    float: left;
    background: darkgrey;
    position: fixed;}

#menu ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: lightblue;
    font-size: 21px;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
         <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
        
    
    </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You have to use Media queries http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: Why not just try to set your container width into 100%?

Answer (score 0):

Remove floats left .It is not necesary while li are display: inline-block. Also revome position fixed in the #menu and your darkgray menu will have 100% width.

```
#menu {
    height: 65px;
    background: darkgrey;
   }
```

[Your code will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obpvt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you but the 100% width isn't the problem.
I want to have my Menu to stick with me if i scroll down.
Thats why i set the position to fixed. But then the Menu is less shorter and i just want it to have a 100% width.

If i correct it with a width of 79% and i resize my screen the Menu sticks out on the right side (outside the container?!?) that i don't understand.

i hope you guys understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use left: 0 instead of float: left.

```
#menu {
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: darkgrey;
  position: fixed;
}
```